# IBAction pushing view control error- "expected expression"

Tags: xcode, view, controller, push, ibaction

Hey guys sorry I was looking around but none of the expected expression error forums on here pertained to mine. I am making my first app and nothing I have learned can help me with this error. I've looked and looked only finding the error in complex apps while mine is pretty basic. Here it is: THIS IS THE UPDATED CODE!!!!!

```
- (IBAction)StartButton:(id)sender;  <--- "Expected Expression"     
{        
   PrimaryViewController *controller = [[PrimaryViewController alloc] 
         initWithNibName:@"PrimaryViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController: controller animated:YES];  
}
```

READ THIS- This is the updated code and the error says on the first line of this "Expected Expression" Thanks!
((((Update:: It is with xibs and the StartViewController is its own class.))))Please please help! On the - (IBAction)... line it says expected expression. I'm trying to push the view controller from the main menu to the start screen when you press the start button IBAction. It is linked to the files menu as well. Thanks!

Comment: Is this with xibs or with storyboards?

Comment: Is StartViewController class name or object?

Comment: It's with xibs and StartViewController is a class.

Comment: you don't need ";" at the end of method signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `StartViewController` and push that.  Trying to push the class itself doesn't make sense.

Something like:

```
StartViewController *controller = [[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: controller animated:YES];
```

(Assuming that's the right name for the .xib file and that you don't already have an instance of `StartViewController` on your navigation stack.)

Comment: Ok I tried that but there is still the same error. I went to a course and pushed the view controller and it worked but I don't have that project with me. I think it might have to do with the IBAction itself. Is there something to import like iostream or something that I might have forgotten? thanks!!

Comment: You also need to get rid of that semicolon as was suggested in the comments.

Comment: sorry I'm probably annoying you but I did remove the semicolon and all the colors were removed. i made another blank application from start and did all the stuff but then I tried adding an IBAction for a random button in the .h which worked but when I added it in the .m it had the same error. i must be doing something wrong!

Comment: Maybe you can update your question with the code as it looks after you made the changes. (And paste in a copy of the exact error?)

Comment: You didn't get rid of the ';' on the IBAction line as @jackiedigital suggested.

Comment: oh yeah but I tried that and everything was unhighlited and same error occured so I put it back for the time being.

Comment: I don't know what else I can tell you: it's wrong.  It's entirely possible that there's another error in the code above what you've shown that's responsible for the message you're seeing but that doesn't make the semicolon correct.

Comment: Alright I appreciate your help, and I'm glad I got a response. I'm going to keep trying until it works. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The error might be because you are entering the IBAction method inside some other class..make sure it is entered after all other methods..just before the @end (after all }'s)